# "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited" Error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

For my discord bot, I'm trying to make if it the bots offline when a 'quote' is said (a message from a specific channel), I can run a command to run through all the quotes and re-add them.

The problem with it is I'm getting an error stating that a coroutine wasn't awaited on line 125. I'm very confused about how to fix this so I'm hoping someone here would know what to do.

Here's the command code for the bot.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def refresh_quotes(ctx):
    with open("quotes.json", "r") as f:
        quotes = json.load(f)
    count = 1
    async with ctx.channel.typing():
        channel = bot.get_channel(819715867424194581)
        messages = await channel.history(limit=None, oldest_first=True).flatten()
        for i in messages:
            quotes.pop(str(count))
            with open("quotes.json", 'w') as f:
                json.dump(quotes, f, indent=4)
            quotes[str(count)] = str(i.content)
            with open("quotes.json", 'w') as f:
                json.dump(quotes, f, indent=4)
            count += 1
    await ctx.send("Successfully refreshed quotes.json.") # Line 125
```

Comment: Did you pay attention to the correct indentation?

Comment: Yes, I believe that I have the correct indentation in the command. The console also said nothing about incorrect indentation.

Comment: Which line is line 125? Also, `ctx.channel.typing()` can just be `ctx.typing()`.

Comment: Line 125 is the bottom line, await ctx.send(). Also, thanks for that, I didnt know that.

Comment: Can you try indenting the last line inside the context manager, like in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel%20typing#discord.DMChannel.typing)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by trial and error. Here's the finished piece in case anyone needs it:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def refresh_quotes(ctx, guild=None):
    if guild is None:
        guild = ctx.guild
    with open(f"quotes/{guild.id}/quotes.json", "r") as f:
        quotes = json.load(f)
    count = 1
    async with ctx.channel.typing():
        channel = bot.get_channel(819715867424194581)
        messages = await channel.history(limit=None, oldest_first=True).flatten()
        try:
            for i in messages:
                with open(f"quotes/{guild.id}/quotes.json", 'w') as f:
                    json.dump(quotes, f, indent=4)
                quotes[str(count)] = str(i.content)
                count += 1
                if count % 10 == 0:
                    await asyncio.sleep(1)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            await ctx.send(f"Quotes aren't set up in this server! To set it up, use 
            ``{get_prefix(ctx.message)}setup "
                       f"quotes`` in the text channel you want to put quotes.")
        finally:
            with open(f"quotes/{guild.id}/quotes.json", 'w') as f:
                json.dump(quotes, f, indent=4)
            await ctx.send(f"Successfully refreshed quotes for server.")
```